# Eliminating Negative Voltage Pulses (≤ 840 mV)

Tags: voltage, transistors, voltage-measurement, zener, schottky

[image]

I have obtained a voltage signal from a Weigand sensor (a sensor that creates a low voltage signal when placed in a rotating alternate magnetic field), which generates a positive pulse of 1.2 V and negative pulses (≤840 mV) in a rotating alternate magnetic field.

I intend to feed this signal into the GPIO pin of an STM32L4xx microcontroller. While the negative voltage is relatively low and unlikely to impact the GPIO pin, I am considering eliminating these negative pulses for adherence to safety SOPs.

I attempted to reduce the negative signal using a Zener diode circuit but faced challenges due to the ON state voltage threshold of Zener diodes falling within the range of 2-200 V, while the pulse magnitude is only 1.2 V. Subsequently, I explored the use of Schottky diodes, known for their low forward bias voltage (0.2-0.3 V). Unfortunately, I did not achieve positive results. If you have experience with low-voltage drop diodes and can provide guidance on resolving this issue, I would greatly appreciate your insights.

Comment: Do you need to measure an analog voltage range or just trigger digitally on some value?

Comment: A link to the data sheet of the sensor is required.

Comment: @Andyaka datasheet Link https://www.elecrow.com/download/K5004477604.pdf
We use WG112.

Comment: Why not use the WG514 and get a digital output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.2V will not be detected as logic level 1 by the GPIO, so you can use:

- A transistor to level shift to 3V3
- An external comparator
- One of the analog comparators inside your STM32

Regarding input protection:

[image]

The transistor case is very simple: with an input protection resistor, input voltage can go quite high, limited by resistor value and maximum base current spec. A diode ensures Vbeo does not go below its max rating.

For the others, I've used a 2V7 Zener diode to limit positive voltage. It is also a diode, so it limits negative voltage, but it will be around -0.6V which is out of spec. So Schottky diode D1 could be added. However, the GPIO input voltage spec really is about ensuring the MCU's internal input protection diodes do not burn out from too much current. So if the Zener diode limits voltage to -0.6V, and a few kOhm protection resistor (R2,R4) is added before the MCU's input, then the input current will be limited to a few tens of µA which is safe. In this case the extra Schottky diode is not really needed.

Comment: Hello, bobflux we have tested and the third logic works perfectly fine. Thanks for helping us.

Comment: Hello Bobflux, I hope you're doing well. I have a question about the circuit. I'm currently utilizing a 2N2222 NPN transistor to switch it ON with positive pulses, and it functions adequately. However, we are facing challenges with low input voltage and low-frequency signals, particularly when the input is below 30Hz; the transistor fails to switch ON effectively. Could you kindly recommend a transistor, OP-AMP, or MOSFET that can be activated with even smaller input voltages and lower signal frequencies? Thanks once again for your assistance.

Comment: Bipolar transistors like 2N2222 (or cheaper 3906) have 0.6V threshold voltage, so it won't work with input voltage lower than this. In this case you have to use a comparator like LM339

Answer (score 2):

I'd buffer or amplify the signal (e.g. non-inv) using a single-supply op-amp. That'd eliminate the negative parts, reduce the potential risks of loading the sensor, and also make the amplitudes (if amplified) more "suitable" for detection or being read by a 3V MCU.

Comment: Which is a wise thing if your opamp can deal with negative input further out the negative supply than your microcontroller can. But that might simply be a matter of adding a series resistor, to limit the current that flows out of the input in that case. But you could do the same on the GPIO. Question is how much larger the input resistance of your opamp is compared to your GPIO pin.

Comment: That, or biasing it up with a resistor divider, or coupling capacitor, schottky diode clamp, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This would seem to be an application of the *precision rectifier* configuration of an operational amplifier.

You'll want an opamp that can do down to is negative rail, or you want a small switch mode power supply IC to generate a negative supply voltage. These aren't complicated.

But looking at the signal:

This seems periodic; I don't know whether absolute voltages matter to you. If they don't, you could use a capacitor to couple the signal onto a bias voltage somewhere in the middle of your ADC range. *AC coupling* is a very common technique.

Comment: Small note: the simplest non-inverting precision rectifiers drive the op amp into hard saturation when the input is negative, so they can be kind of slow. There are a number of "improved precision rectifier" circuits that avoid this, most requiring two op amps for a non-inverted output.