# Asking Question about Low Voltage Transistor, MOSFET or op-amp for a Conditioning Circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, mosfet, low-voltage

Which transistor, MOSFET or op-amp, can I use in place of the 2N2222 NPN transistor to turn ON the circuit for the lowest input voltage in mvolts.

***Explanation:***
I've obtained a voltage signal from a Weigand sensor (a sensor that creates a low voltage signal when placed in a rotating alternate magnetic field). It generates a positive pulse of 1.2 V and negative pulses (≤840 mV) in the rotating alternate magnetic field as shown in Figure#01.

I attempted to reduce the negative voltage signal using the conditioning circuit depicted in Figure #02, and it works fine. However, I'm encountering an issue where the NPN transistor (2N2222) fails to turn ON properly for low-frequency (<30 Hz) input signals, as illustrated in Figure #03. In other words, the transistor does not switch ON for low input voltages.

[image: Figure01, Figure02, and Figure03]

Comment: Did you ask [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/694620/eliminating-negative-voltage-pulses-%e2%89%a4-840-mv) using a different log-in name?

Comment: @Andyaka And an identical one, now deleted, from this morning.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes I Asked. After that, I was deleted due to some incomplete info.

Comment: @UbaidUllah - Hi, Your use of this site is abnormal. (a) As far as I can tell, *this* is a "delete & repost" with one clarification, of [your previous question](/q/696187). That is the wrong etiquette here. Instead, on Stack Exchange, a question should be edited to improve it - not reposted with small improvements. Don't repost this again. Clarify/improve *this* one, if needed. (b) It seems your "Figure01" is copied from a post by another user who asked this [original question](/q/694620). In order to comply with the [site rule on referencing](/help/referencing) {...}

Comment: (continued) {...} you must add links to that question & their username as the original source, when *you* include a copy of material (e.g. an image) from *their* question. As you see, you are causing extra work and complications for yourself, by copying material from someone else. I don't know the connection between you and that user (colleague? classmate?) but it may be easier if they asked questions instead of you after this one, as they do not need to add references to their own material, even if they use it in multiple questions, if it is theirs.